# createMinToInstruction authorized by PDA, works in LocalNet, but gives "Account not associated with this Mint" on DevNet

Tags: pda, devnet, mint, createminttoinstruction

I create an automated deployment script that will mint 2 million SPL tokens to an address, the mint is owned by the program PDA as shown in Solana explorer:

[image: 1]

Bellow is the last step in the deployment script:

```
export async function mint2e6Tokens(provider: anchor.AnchorProvider, tokenAccount: PublicKey, mint: PublicKey): Promise<void> {
  // get the token account could be PDA
  const programKeypair = await createKeypairFromFile(PROGRAM_KEYPAIR_PATH);
  /** Load from PDA */
  let mint_tokens_tx = new Transaction().add(
    createMintToInstruction(
      mint,
      tokenAccount,
      programKeypair.publicKey, // -> I DOUBLE CHECKED, THIS IS 6Z24B3qCrWfWvDo1f2HgxmnBSGhqQes1sHobqMtMxfbP
      2e6,
      [],
      TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
    )
  );
  // We sign with our programId instead of the wallet because this is a PDA
  // Program Derived Adress
  await provider.sendAndConfirm(mint_tokens_tx, [programKeypair]);
}
```

When I run in LocalNet, it works:

```
Migrating to LocalNet...
RUNNING CUSTOM SCRIPT ====>>> 
Payper: EsgJ9ihTEZskWyWpMMPuGVisy5ay76YWgetgTLb3jRmj
Using program 6Z24B3qCrWfWvDo1f2HgxmnBSGhqQes1sHobqMtMxfbP
Program: 6Z24B3qCrWfWvDo1f2HgxmnBSGhqQes1sHobqMtMxfbP
Mint: AVPgrT1y6ZfjGWPyLCWEPZdogRgmEMbrdRbcHNSfAPzF
Campaign: FcAmyEgZsXUKLB6hKufDmLuSBzMzVtPmRPm7vZLStK4U
31999500
```

However when I switch to DevNet, it always give me error

```
Migrating to DevNet...
RUNNING CUSTOM SCRIPT ====>>> 
Payper: EsgJ9ihTEZskWyWpMMPuGVisy5ay76YWgetgTLb3jRmj
Using program 6Z24B3qCrWfWvDo1f2HgxmnBSGhqQes1sHobqMtMxfbP
Program: 6Z24B3qCrWfWvDo1f2HgxmnBSGhqQes1sHobqMtMxfbP
Mint: AVPgrT1y6ZfjGWPyLCWEPZdogRgmEMbrdRbcHNSfAPzF
Campaign: FcAmyEgZsXUKLB6hKufDmLuSBzMzVtPmRPm7vZLStK4U
SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x3
    at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (/code/beens/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:4248:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Connection.sendRawTransaction (/code/beens/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:4210:20)
    at async sendAndConfirmRawTransaction (/code/beens/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/provider.ts:288:21)
    at async AnchorProvider.sendAndConfirm (/code/beens/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/provider.ts:148:14) {
  logs: [
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Instruction: MintTo',
    'Program log: Error: Account not associated with this Mint',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 2809 of 200000 compute units',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA failed: custom program error: 0x3'
  ]
}
```

Why the authority is right, but Solana complains that **Error: Account not associated with this Mint**?

Comment: Is the tokenAccount created for the mint in devnet? probably the issue is tokenAccount not having the same mint or not being initialized

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the response. I figured out that the right Anchor version is very crucial to move from localhost -> devnet -> testnet -> mainnet. Check the version release note, sometime the newest version will not work with testnet or mainnet.